# Pass values from two or more MainWindows (SDI application) in Qt

Tags: qt, settings, shared, children, qmainwindow

I am writing a SDI (Single Document Interface) application with the Qt framework.

I am currently stuck with a "small" problem: If I change a preference in one MainWindow, I would like that all the other instances of the same MainWindow to load that preference, say:

**Window 2:**

1. User changes toolbar visibility (hides it).
2. Settings are saved with using the QSettings feature.

**All other windows (can be as many as the user wants):**

1. Detect that Window 2 saved the settings.
2. Apply the new settings.

I have tried many things, such as using SIGNALS/SLOTS, but I cannot change all windows because the way that MainWindows are created in my app are so:

Window 1 creates Window 2:

- Window 2 creates Window 3:

  - Window 3 creates Window 4:

    - And so on...

This means that if a change a value in Window 3, only Window 2 will load the new settings.

Do you know a way of doing this (how pass values to all children (and parents) of a window)?

Comment: You can find an example of how I solved this issue [here](http://pastebin.com/mzvH61fw).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `QApplication::topLevelWidgets()` to get a list of top-level widgets (windows). You'd call it like this: `qApp->topLevelWidgets()`.

There are multiple ways of notifying those widgets about the changes. I've listed some of them below; the list is by no means exhaustive, there are many more ways of doing it.

1. You can use a `QObject` to store your settings in dynamic properties. You can emit a signal when any property is changed. Reimplement `QObject::event()` to handle `QDynamicPropertyChangeEvent` that the object will receive whenever a dynamic property is changed. Whenever a property is changed, you can simply store it in QSettings. The object's initial property values can be retrieved from QSettings upon construction.
2. Emit a signal manually whenever you change settings, and connect it to each SDI window at the point when you create it. This doesn't require using the `topLevelWidgets()` method.
3. Use a custom model, say derived from `QAbstractListModel`, and attach your windows to the `dataChanged` signal of the model.

Comment: Hi, I uploaded an example of how I connected the signals and slots between all MainWindows [here](http://pastebin.com/mzvH61fw).